# SSRS - Using database names as parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I have 2 databases both having same table structures but with different data. I want to display a report by giving a filter to choose the database name. I tried using connection string as expression in Embedded connection still it's not working.

Comment: Are databases on the same server?

Comment: Post your expression for embedded connection

Comment: Yes databases are on same server.

Comment: @Anton expression is ="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=" + Parameters!dbname.Value

Comment: what is the error? have you tried SQL Profiler?

Comment: No. I haven't tried that.

Comment: @Anton when I try to use data source(where i have put the expression) for a dataset there I'm getting this following error - Connection string expressions cannot be evaluated at design time. You must preview or deploy the report to verify the connection.

Comment: You need to use a hardcoded datasource during design time, and then change it to expression just before deployment.

Comment: @Anton How do I change the expression just before deployment?

Comment: ok,let's start again. What is 'it's not working'? You can't save what you entered into expression, or you can't continue designing it? or it does not work in Production?

Comment: it's hard to troubleshoot it when you don't see it. Read these links, it may help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4302/implement-dynamic-data-sources-in-sql-server-reporting-services/  http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2012/08/how-to-use-dynamic-data-sources-in-your.html I'll have to go soon...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this but this has a limitation: the datasource cannot be shared.
So the sequence is following:

- create a report using embedded datasource and "fixed" connection string like `Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db1`, using a wizard or how you want, make sure it can be refreshed
- create a parameter dbname
- substitute the expression in datasource to by dynamic: `="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=" &Parameters!dbname.Value`

Comment: I've tried it and it worked perfect. Did you use & this time? Does the parameter exist?

Comment: Yes parameter exists and I used &. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @user7814194 You are getting this error not while creating the datasource but when trying to create a field list for dataset, right? I've just got the same error, so even if we can create such a datasource it's useless...

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to use this datasource for another dataset. And I can't hard code connection string because I want to use parameter in report to select between number of databases and display data from that particular database.

Comment: The point was to create a dataset with all it fields using "fixed" datasource, not dynamic. The dynamic datasource definition was rigth but it is not permitting to evaluate the fields, so it should be done using non dynamic database name, and only then you can substitute your datasource definition with dynamic database name